# MySQL fullsearch question

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a database that is about 200MB. It has about 140 tables and its completely MyISAM based. I'm planning to perform a fulltext search almost 100,000 a day. Should I make any improvements so that MySQL does not give me any problems?

Comment: Too little information. You should give the size and structure of tables where fulltext search will be performed (I suppose all your tables are not the same, are they).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... it depends.

If spread evenly over 24 hours that is just over one search per second, if most of them happen between 10AM and 4PM then you have almost 5 per second. How long do your searchs take on average?

You don't mention your hardware set up or plans in the event of hardware failure so I can't comment. How critical is the information being searched? Is it "find me a restaurant" non-critical or "find me a a patient for this heart so I can transplant it" critical?

Comment: It currently takes only 0.004 seconds to perform one search and I have Intel Quad-core 6600 with 8GB RAM.

Comment: The information is being searched is merely 2 or 3 words at a time.

Comment: Sounds to me like the only significant exposure is a hardware failure then.